# Is there a way to cancel (or pause or postpone) a Mirror/RAID Resynch in Disk Management (Win2k3)

Tags: raid, software-raid, windows-server-2003

I have a software RAID setup in Windows Server 2003, which recently had a disk go bad. I replaced the disk, and rebuilt the array. Every time I reboot though, it automatically starts rebuilding the array. The resynching slows disk access down to a crawl, so is there a way to stop or pause it. I have 1 RAID 5, and 2 separate Mirrors, and its trying to resynch all 3 arrays at the same time. This basically makes my bootup time over 48 hours! I'd like to postpone the array rebuilds until after I copy all my precious data off it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pull the disk out. It's going to provide you the same level of redundancy than an array that's rebuilding anyway (ie none)

Comment: I love the simplicity. I'll give it a shot. Still would be nice to know if there is anything I could do from the software side of things.

Comment: No Good, thing won't boot with one of the drives out. Any other ideas?

Comment: Are you removing the disk that's in the process of being rebuilt (i.e. the one that replaced the failed one)? If the disk failed, that's kinda the point of RAID...

Comment: I have a really strange setup that is contributing to my problems. I have 4 physical disks, 200GB each. I have a 40GB mirror using 40GB of the first 2 drives, I also have another 40GB mirror using 40GB of the other 2 drives. Then, with the extra space on each of the 4 drives, there is a RAID 5 setup.

Comment: Are the disks hot-swappable? Can you boot up with the disk in place, then just yoink it out?

Comment: It's a bit odd that it won't start up though, because removing one disk seems like it should degrade one RAID-1 and one RAID-5 array, which should still leave them both operational. Still, if you can't boot with the disk out I'm afraid I'm all out of ideas!

Answer (score 0):

Caveat -- this is not for a RAID 5, but for a RAID 1.  Hopefully, it also applies to RAID 5, to remove the drive being synchronized.  In any case, it is wisdom to perform an image-level backup before doing anything.

Select the disk that is not good yet, right click on its mirrored volume, and choose "Remove Mirror..." from the menu.

[image: Disk2 with warning triangle, right-clicking on Volume, choosing "Remove Mirror..."]

When it asks which disk, choose the disk not yet synchronized (shown by warning triangle), and click "Remove Mirror":

[image: "Remove Mirror" dialog box, with two items, Disk 1, and Disk 2, which is selected and has a yellow exclamation warning triangle on it, showing that Disk 1 is Healthy, and Disk 2 is synchronizing to disk 1 and not yet Healthy]

This should stop the synchronization process and allow you to copy the files off of the drive. The end state should look like this:

[image: "Disk Management" showing the volume just removed as Unallocated space, and the healthy volume ready to be used.]

That's it.  HTH.